# Same response is given multiple times when refused to sign-in in google assistant

Tags: dialogflow-es, actions-on-google

We ask user to sign in one of our intent, when user refuses to sign-in, we close the conversation with conv.close giving thank you message. google assistant gives the same response of "Thank you for using sample app" multiple times.

What is the reason for multiple messages? How can we fix it?

For the reference, screenshot is attached

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This is a known bug on Google's side, apparently. I understand they're aware of it and a fix is in the works.